# Fraunhofer Diffraction - Multiple Square Apertures

Tags: optics, diffraction

I'm stuck for some days trying to get the diffraction pattern from a binary grating / square period grating / multi-aperture square screen... whatever you want to call it.

Imagine I have a 8 * 5 square apertures grating. Something like this:

[image: Multi Aperture Example]

The intensity profile from a single aperture is easy to calculate:

[image: Equation]

```
% Clean all
clc;
close all;
clear all;

% Light Source
lambda = 550e-9;                    % Wavelength [m]
k = (2*pi)/lambda;                  % Wavenumber [m^-1]
Io = 100;                           % Relative intensity

% Aperture
a = 1e-6;                           % Aperture size X-axis [m]
b = 1e-6;                           % Aperture size Y-axis [m]

% Screen
R = 1e-3;                           % Distance aperture-screen [m]
dsize = 0.5e-2;                     % Square size [m]
dpix = 1000;                        % Dimension [pixel]
X = -dsize:2*dsize/dpix:dsize;      % Screen X-axis
Y = X;                              % Screen Y-axis

% Intensity Profile
alpha = k*a*X/(2*pi*R);                     % Periodic parameter X-axis
beta = k*b*Y/(2*pi*R);                      % Periodic parameter Y-axis
I = Io*(sinc(alpha).^2)'*(sinc(beta).^2);   % Intensity profile

% Print
fig = figure();
imshow(I);
```

[image: Diffraction]

To calculate the same for a 8 * 5 grating, I have to do a convolution of my unit-square aperture by a comb function. I will get an infinite pattern. Then I just have to multiply it by rectangular (sinc) function to get a non-infinite pattern. But I'm struggling with it.

I would like to get something to input in Matlab.

Could you advise me?

[image: Equation 2]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be asking for Matlab coding instead of the theoretical aspects of diffraction. Also "I'm struggling with it" is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

So you have a square aperture convolved with a 2D comb. The Fourier transform of a convolution becomes a product; the Fourier transform of a comb is another comb; and the Fourier transform of a square aperture is a 2D sinc-function. So, you end up with the 2D sinc-function multiplied by a comb. For a finite array you them have to convolve the result with a small 2D sinc-function that comes from the overall square aperture. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I would like to do a numerical simulation in Matlab. But I don't know how to input my function on it. Matlab can interpret a sinc function but not a comb function.

Perhaps I could do it in this way: SUM[rect[ (x-x_ij)/a , (y-y_ij)/a]. ("i" and "j" are the matrix indexs). But it's not working...

Comment: Any simulation that you would do in Matlab would imply a finite domain. The implication is that you get everything convolved with since functions. Unless you understand what you see in Matlab, it would be better to do this analytically.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got in python (I used a 7x7 grid but it should be very similar).
[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/445657)

Comment: Yes, I wanted to post it as a comment to someone else's answer (which got removed now I think), but I did not have enough reputation. I do not actually know how to answer the question posed, I just thought that the plot I generated might be useful.